# Error: opentelemetry-collector: - topologySpreadConstraints: Invalid type. Expected: array, given: object

Tags: kubernetes-helm, open-telemetry, skaffold, otel

Getting error

```
topologySpreadConstraints: Invalid type. Expected: array, given: object
```

in

```
skaffold dev
```

or

```
tilt up
```

My skaffold.yaml file has the following helm release configuration:

```
  helm:
    releases:
      - name: opentelemetry-collector
        repo: https://open-telemetry.github.io/opentelemetry-helm-charts
        remoteChart: opentelemetry-collector
        valuesFiles: [ "otel-collector/values.yaml" ]
```

```
skaffold dev
```

command should have run successfully

Answer (score 2):

This is actually to do with the latest changes in opentelemetry-helm-charts repo which is related to topologySpreadContraints(Refer to [https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-helm-charts/commit/3a87156d4760914e244e39b8edec6335297da68e]). They've changed the data type of topologySpreadContraints from an object to an array.

So just check with your opentelemetry-collector config file (values.yaml) where you would have set the field topologySpreadConstraints. Consider changing its type to an array like this: `topologySpreadConstraints: []`. This is an example of an empty array that is currently used in my values.yaml file.